# Writing an API in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, api

I'm developing a new kind of platform and I want to use Eclipse as an IDE for my API. I want to program the API in C and have the application in C. I got the idea of building an API in Eclipse from Android. How would I go about this?

Comment: If your API is a C API, then you don't really have to do anything in Eclipse besides publish your API documentation.  If you want to write an Eclipse plug-in, this is independent of writing a library or API.  What exactly would you want this plug-in to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to write an API using Eclipse as an IDE or do you want to write something that runs on top of Eclipse?  For the first, lookup "CDT".  For the second, look at the Eclipse Plugin Development Toolkit, which is Java based (of course you can wrap C/C++), but be warned its not trivial.